# Subscript out of range with sheet reference from cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I get this message with the following block of code. I know I'm not defining my range correctly but I'm a bit lost. Thanks!

```
 Sub clean_data()


Dim Preliminary_MTM As Worksheet
Dim Sheetlink As String

Sheetlink = Worksheets("Input for model").Range("E17").Value

Set Preliminary_MTM = Sheets(Sheetlink)

Preliminary_MTM.Activate
```

Comment: On which line exactly do you get this error ?

Comment: Is the sheet you're trying to get in the same workbook?

Comment: What's the value in `E17`?

Comment: `Sheets` are not same as `Worksheets`. Use just one of them.

Comment: As @cyboashu said - [Sheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets) covers all sheets in the workbook - chart sheets, worksheets and old style macro sheets included.  [Worksheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet) just covers the basic worksheet. It shouldn't cause a problem though.

Comment: Do you have two sheets in your workbook 1. Input for model and 2. sheet with exact name as the value of cell E17 in Input from model sheet ?

Comment: Value in E17 is Worksheets("Preliminary MTM Q1")

Comment: Do you actually have a worksheet named "Input for model" with that exact spacing? Do you have a worksheet with the exact text content of whatever is in cell E17 of the "Input for model" worksheet?

Comment: the sheet is in the same workbook

Comment: yep, I tried activating the sheet by naming it directly instead of a link and it does work.

Comment: Value in E17 should be `Preliminary MTM Q1` not `Worksheets("Preliminary MTM Q1")`

Comment: code works for me, definitely an issue with cell contents or sheet names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment that the contents of cell "E17" is exactly `Worksheets("Preliminary MTM Q1")` then you would have to have a worksheet named "Worksheets("Preliminary MTM Q1")" (i.e. that's what you would see on the worksheet tab in your Excel file) and my guess is you don't have one with that name. As a matter of fact, you *can't* have a worksheet with that name because it's too long:

[image]

What you want in E17 is simply `Preliminary MTM Q1` so that when you reference it in this code:

```
Set Preliminary_MTM = Worksheets(Worksheets("Input for model").Range("E17").Value2)
```

it accesses the contents of that cell and looks for the worksheet named there.

Note: I've changed `.Value` for `.Value2`. `.Value2` gives you the completely unformatted text in the cell, while `.Value` will return formatting information - this can cause problems.

Note: I've reduced the code to the one line because that's all that's necessary. If you're actually using the variable `sheetlink` elsewhere, then you'll need to include that.

Comment: Excellent point, @Jeeped - thanks for noticing that. I've fixed it

Comment: I think you're incorrect with the Value2 - [The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2)